# Weird pixels everywhere in phonegap

Tags: webview, mobile-website, mobile-webkit

I'm developing a cross-platform application and I'm having a bug with only one of the test devices I have: The tablet HP Slate8 Pro (model 7600es).

The problem is that in many places of the display, there are weird pixels, like it doesn't get anti-alias-ed properly. Here are a few screenshots of what I mean:

[image: Pixel bug]

The first one gets pretty clear. It's a part from a linear plot, and this green line just gets weird. Same for the circles.
The second one is harder to see, but there's a grey line in the middle that's also kind of broken, and the 8 and the second zero are not right
And finally, the last one is some text that's also wrong.

My viewport meta tag is:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width,
              initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

And my cordova version is 3.4.1-0.1.0

What's really strange though, is that the last app I made with cordova doesn't have this bug in the same tablet. The main difference between these two is that the old one was made with AngularJS and Bootstrap and this one is made with Ionic (That works on AngularJS as well). I don't really know if this could be related.

Also, testing this app directly in the Chrome browser of the same device, the bug doesn't show up. Then I think it only happens when using the cordova's WebView.

Anyone has any hint?

======= EDIT ========

I just found that putting `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` in the viewport meta tag "patches" this issue by disallowing density resize, thus making everything look way smaller than it should making my application almost unusable.

So, it really looks like the WebView is scaling all the webpage to match mdpi dimensions, but fails at anti-aliasing the resized pixels.

Probably I will post an issue to ionic.

Comment: Does this issue happen inside a canvas ?

Comment: In and out of the canvas. The linear plot is in a canvas, but the text is in HTML and is also wrong

Comment: For the canvas, you can take a look at [this article on HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/), but for the text, I've got not idea, sorry